# iOS - UITapGesture did begin and end?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

## Question:

I'm trying to change the background color of a view using `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Essentially when the user taps, I want the background to change colors, and on release or complete, the background color go back to nil, or no background color.

This action is similar to a default `UIButton`, but I need this to be on a view instead.

## Problem:

I've tried using code similar to:

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
        if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        
        if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            self.backgroundColor = nil;
        }
}
```

without any sucess.  Is this the correct way to know when a tap gesture starts and ends?

Comment: How do you add your gesture to your view ? Aru you sure that - handleTapGesture is correctly called ?

Comment: You are setting the backgroundColor for "self". Is self a (subclass of) UIView?

Comment: @Scott Yes, self is a subclass of UIView.

Comment: @Pierre the tap is handled in the `initWithCoder` and I know it is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to use these methods which should already be part of the responder chain in your UIViewController, unless they are being handled elsewhere already

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    //CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"began");
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"end");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards or somehow through interface builder you could use a UIButton, drag it out a bit to form it into a background and then you can set it so that when a touch event is received, a different custom colour is displayed for the duration of the background image being held down.

Hope that helps!